# Some problems with a proof of the Farkas Lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

The following is a proof of the Farkas Lemma that is creating me quite some problems.
[I presented the all proof simply to point out the notation used by the author.]

My problem is with the last part of the proof (i.e. the last png file with the red frame), namely the part in which the author shows that the procedure terminates.

**[Below the proof there are my problems and my thoughts over them.]**

[image]
[image]
[image]

[I will highlight the problems with a number.]

First of all, trying to get the structure behind this last part, it seems to me that the author proceeds by contradiction. In particular, **step 3** can be translated in the following way: $$\forall a^j \in A (y a^j \geq 0 \Longrightarrow STOP)$$
By assuming it and procedeeing by contradiction we have that exists a $a^j \in A$ such that $y a^j \geq 0$, and that $\forall k,l (k<l \Longrightarrow D^k = D^l)$.

Now, the idea looks to me that $D^p$ and $D^q$ differs at least by $a^s$. Honestly, I am not completely sure on the idea of inserting $a^s$ back after the iteration $q$.

**1)** I mean, I see why it has to be the case, but is it enough to proceed with it?

**2)** Slightly changing the focus, but basically staying on the same issue, why do we write $D^p \cap \{ a^{s+1}, \dots, a^n \} = D^q \cap \{ a^{s+1}, \dots, a^n \}$? Is it partly for the reason I mentioned before, namely that $D^p$ and $D^q$ differs at least by $a^s$, and that, following from this remark, this is the most compact notation to highlight what the sets have in common?

Frankly, after this point, things start to be so fuzzy that I even have problems to actually come up with precise questions over my doubts. Moreover I am not sure about the notation (e.g. at the end $D^p \cap \{ a^{s+1}, \dots, a^r \} = D^q \cap \{ a^{r+1}, \dots, a^r \}$).

Is there somebody that can help me?
Any feedback will be greatly appreciated (and please point out my mistakes without any mercy!).
Thank you.

Comment: Do you know much about convex analysis? If yes, I'll give you very nice and short proof.

Comment: @Richkent: First of all, thanks a lot to have shown interest in this rather old post. To answer your question: I am slowly getting into it. However, my problem was not on finding a concise proof of the result (I actually found quite some, and there is one in particular that should be famous because it is really short - probably the one you are referring to), but rather on understanding this specific proof. So to speak, I was using it as a test of my mathematical maturity. However, now I have to admit I should go back on it, because I lost touch on these lines.